# 9-patch with two stretchable regions doesn't work appropriately

Tags: android, nine-patch

I've a 9-patch image which contains 2 horizontal stretchable areas and 2 vertical stretchable areas like this. It looks good in `draw9patch` and the emulator.

[image: draw9patch screenshot]

Unfortunately it becomes strange in real devices, I tested it with Asus Nexus 7 (Android 4.4.3) tab and Sony Xperia Tipo ST21i (Android 4.0.4) phone. This is a view set that drawable as the background.

[image: Asus Nexus screenshot]

Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Comment: I believe it is not center aligned because you have 4 empty pixels from the left and 3 from the right. Which also brings up the question about densities.. Im wondering what res folder your 9-patch is placed to? Try to place it into drawable-nodpi folder

Comment: I think 4 and 3 pixels will not make big difference while it stretching because the stretchable areas has the same width. It is placed under `drawable-hpdi`. I think placing in `drawable-nodpi` is not a best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this was because of scaling of the base image to adapt screen density. The image in the question is for hdpi. Widen the stretching area from 1 px to 2 px solved this problem, **but** it is strange that the circle is not center aligned in Asus Nexus, it is slightly to the right than it should. However it looks fine in Sony Xperia (centered).

So, I still wait for another better answer.